# Finding parameters of a normal distribution from transformed samples

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, algorithms, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation

We want to find the parameters of a multivariate normal distribution $N_d(\mu,\Sigma)$ which approximates a known vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as follows

- First, sample $t$-times from a multivariate normal distribution $y_j
     \sim N_d(\mu,\Sigma)$ for $j\in\{1,\ldots,t\}$.
- Then, apply some fixed operator $A$ (for the sake of simplicity we can
  assume linear at first), $A(y_j)=\hat{y}_j\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
- Now, set the $i$-th index of $z_j=(0,\ldots,0)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to $1$ if $\hat{y}_{ji} = \Vert \hat{y}_j\Vert_{max}$. Then, we get $x \approx \frac1t\sum_{j=0}^t z_j$,
  i.e. for each transformed sample we count the index with the maximal value.

For large $t$ we should then approximate $x$.
Clearly, we restrict $x$ to fullfil $\sum_{i=0}^n x_i=1$.

How would you estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$? Since we are working with samples here, I do not know if we could even use classical optimisation tools.

Comment: Do you mean that $x$ is actually a mean of $z_j$ and not $x_j$?

Comment: oh yes, thanks for the hint